# ¿Se puede colocar resplandor intermitente al rededor de una imagen?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, animación

Buen día, quisiera saber si es posible colocar resplandor intermitente al borde de una imagen o de un div al cargar la página (como una publicidad).
Gracias.

Comment: Borde intermitente En esta parte puedo agregar. <img src="Logo.png"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que pides se puede hacer facilmente con CSS3, te dejo los links de la documentación para que la veas ahi lo explican muy bien.
Necesitas crear un keyframes donde defines el comportamiento del objeto a lo largo del tiempo, el tiempo se lo asignas tu que es el tiempo que estara la animacion activa. Despues tan solo hay que aplicar la animacion al objeto o clase.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

```css
.intermitente{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px;
  animation: infinite resplandorAnimation 2s;
  
}
@keyframes resplandorAnimation {
  0%,100%{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px;
  }
  50%{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
  
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  
</head>

<body>
<div class="intermitente">Borde intermitente</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: esta excelente tu respuesta, es posible se pueda cambiar el color del resplandor?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar algo como esto...

```css
#resplandorverde{   
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #A3FF0F; 
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #A3FF0F; 
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #A3FF0F;
      
      padding: 10px;
      width: 160px;
      margin: 40px;
   }
.text {
  font-size:28px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#71d90b;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.parpadea {
  
  animation-name: parpadeo;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -webkit-animation-name:parpadeo;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes parpadeo{  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes parpadeo {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
   100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@keyframes parpadeo {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
   50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

```html
<span id="resplandorverde" class="parpadea">Coloca tu imagen aqui</strong>
```

Comment: si no quieres que el contenido parpadee sino solo el borde, puedes asignarle una posicion absoluta a la imagen y posicionarla sobre el borde, obviamente la imagen debe estar fuera del div/span/etc que contenga la clase "parpadea"